# Can I migrate some questions of mine from Superuser to here?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, migration

I need to know if some questions of mine could be migrated here, if they are appropriate for this site and if by doing so I will get a chance to have them answered.

I write here after being advised to do so in [Superuser meta site](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6745/i-need-advice-on-where-to-move-some-questions-of-mine).

These questions were asked there, but they haven't received a lot of attention, and I'd like to try moving them somewhere else. The questions are:

https://superuser.com/questions/585295/how-to-customize-logout-options-under-linux

https://superuser.com/questions/584446/how-to-properly-configure-grub-settings-from-kde-system-settings

https://superuser.com/questions/586031/quick-usb-pendrive-formatting-under-kde

https://superuser.com/questions/584896/repository-to-upgrade-sigil-to-latest-version-on-kubuntu

Do you think that they have a chance of being successfully answered here? I'm rather new of the StackExchange network and I don't know if they are more appropriate (or have a better chance to be solved) on "Unix and Linux" or on "AskUbuntu".

Any advice?

Comment: Well they all seem to be on-topic here. I can't speak for getting them answered though.

Comment: All your questions you've linked were migrated to U&L within the past day or so.  I think they're OK where they are, on U&L, but if you don't get an answer in a while them maybe a discussion on migration is warranted (however, I think you'll be fine now that the questions are on U&L)  (U&L = Unix&Llinux)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on Kubuntu I would suggest migrating your questions here indeed. I cannot guarantee an answer either.